# Odoo 10 - Get id of a specific record from product_uom

Tags: odoo

I have the following custom UoM defined in the system.

I have an extended model for product and I would like to look programmatically for the id of this specific record, so I can use it in an onchange method.

As the type is created manually, I do not want to hardcode the id as other UoMs might have been defined previously. How do you get from this model (product.uom) the specific id which corresponds to "name" = "MILES" ?

```
 id | create_uid |  name  | rounding | write_uid | uom_type |         write_date         | factor | active |        create_date         | category_id
----+------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+--------+--------+----------------------------+-------------
 20 |          1 | MILES  |    0.001 |         1 | bigger   | 2017-07-12 03:42:25.363007 |  0.001 | t      | 2017-07-12 03:33:27.251635 |           1
```

Comment: what you want exactly specify in details.

Comment: How did you create this unit? Did you just create it in client or do you use a custom module which brings this unit with xml data records into the database?

Comment: I created it using the user interface, but now you mention it, it might be clever to add is as xml data record. If so, would it be possible to refer to it via external id or something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075701/odoo-10-create-a-record-in-product-uom-via-data-xml

Comment: Yes it would. I will add an answer for that. But Odedra's is correct, too.

Comment: thanks, I got an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075701/odoo-10-create-a-record-in-product-uom-via-data-xml/45076503#45076503 although I am still wondering how to uniquely identify that specific record, and how to ensure that it is not loaded twice into the system (noupdate="1")?

Comment: If it already is in the system, Odoo will update the record, if not it will be created. There is no chance having an external ID (`module_name.external_id_name`) twice in Odoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with following ORM *search()* method:

```
self.env['product.uom'].search([('name', '=', 'MILES')], limit=1).id
```

Answer (score 1):

A second approach besides Odedra's is to use external IDs. But you have to either give the unit one by yourself in the client (under Settings) or you provide the unit within your custom module as xml data record, which already require an ID.

Let's say the external ID is `my_module.my_unit_of_measure`, in Odoo python code you will be able to get it by:

```py
self.env.ref('my_module.my_unit_of_measure')
```

In xml or csv files there are some possibilities, too:

```xml
<record id="my_product" model="product.product">
    <!-- required fields -->
    <field name="uom_id" ref="my_module.my_unit_of_measure" />
</record>

<!-- using in filters should work too -->
<filter name="filter_my_unit" string="Products with my unit"
    domain="[('uom_id', '=', ref('my_module.my_unit_of_measure')" />
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this solution is much better for the specific thing I want to do, as it allows me to provide both data and functionality in the custom addon. I will keep Odedra's answer as correct as it answered explicitly to the question I made.