# Odoo 10 - Create a record in product.uom via data/...xml

Tags: odoo

I have to use the following custom UoM defined in the system:

```
 id | create_uid |  name  | rounding | write_uid | uom_type |         write_date         | factor | active |        create_date         | category_id
----+------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+--------+--------+----------------------------+-------------
 20 |          1 | MILES  |    0.001 |         1 | bigger   | 2017-07-12 03:42:25.363007 |  0.001 | t      | 2017-07-12 03:33:27.251635 |           1
```

Could someone provide an example on how to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways insert a new UoM :

1. Using xml file :

   Go to addons/product/product_data.xml

```xml
    <record id="product_uom_unit" model="product.uom">
        <field name="category_id" ref="product_uom_categ_unit"/>
        <field name="name">Unit(s)</field>
        <field name="factor" eval="1.0"/>
        <field name="rounding" eval="0.001"/>
    </record>
```

Or using .csv file :

1. Go to settings/configuration/warehouse, and check the 5th option in Location & Warehouse, `Manage different units of measure for products`
2. Go to warehouse/configuration/unite of mesure, in tree view export the data, then you can add a new UoM to this file

[image]

Comment: How can I later refer to that specific record? I mean, which will be its external id and how can I refer to that external id in python code?

Comment: @usk70, you have not to use an external id, you can use its name instead